# The functions I'm passing arent getting run by azure function app

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, azure

I'm trying to get my function app to log dta to an azure table. I followed the examples but the function that I'm giving as a callback isn't run.

I have tried running this on a node server locally on my machine and it works fine, therefore I assume it is an issue with azure?
I have also tried creating a new function app with no unnecessary node packages to see whether they were the problem, but it didn't help.

```js
module.exports = async function(context, req) {

  var tableSvc = azure.createTableService('account name', 'access key');
  tableSvc.createTableIfNotExists('mytable', function(error, result, response) {
    context.log("Reached this point");
    if (!error) {
      context.log(result);
    }
  });

}
```

I expect to see "Reached this point " in the function app logs 
as well as the result - if there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

The function is completing after you send the request to Storage but before you hit `context.log("Reached this point");` so the logging is not occurring even though the table is being created. Since `createTableIfNotExists()` does not return a promise that you can await, you need to run the function synchronously and use `context.done()` to let the runtime know when the function has completed.

```
module.exports = function(context, req) {

var tableSvc = azure.createTableService('account name', 'access key');

tableSvc.createTableIfNotExists('mytable', function(error, result, response) {
  context.log("Reached this point");
  if (!error) {
    context.log(result);
  }

  context.done();
  });
}
```